# Assign a gridster data-row dynamically after creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I have created few gridsters and now wants to sort them programmatically.For example, in following case using `data-displayorder` attribute.

```
<div data-displayorder="7" id="GridsterContent01" class="panel panel-filled panel-responsive js-reportTable gs-w" data-col="1" data-row="31" data-sizex="20" data-sizey="5" style="display: block;">
  <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span>
</div>

<div data-displayorder="4" id="GridsterContent-2" class="panel panel-filled panel-responsive js-reportTable gs-w" data-col="1" data-row="31" data-sizex="20" data-sizey="5" style="display: block;">
  <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span>
</div>
```

I tried doing that using jQuery, but this takes out the size and style.

```
 var sortPriorirty = $(this).attr('data-displayOrder');
  $(this).attr('data-row', sortPriorirty );
```

Is there an API to assign `gridster` data-row after creation?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an extra rows bettween grids.

```
var sortPriorirty = $(this).attr('data-displayOrder');
  $(this).attr('data-row', sortPriorirty+5 );
```